# How can I add users in ApostropheCMS?

Tags: authentication, apostrophe-cms

I'm using ApostropheCMS. I want to add users authentication to my project. How can I do this? The users should be created in the same way I created admin user? (via /login page and apostrophe-users module).

I want to create a custom form for both login and registration. Then I want to check if the user is log in and if so, I want an user profile for them.

Answer (score 1):

There's a module you can install to add a signup form: https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-signup